# Getter/Setter In Typescript

Tags: typescript

I was following a tutorial on Typescript Classes and the person teaching created a class and some setter/getter methods.But when i read [Typescript Documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html) the approach was somewhat different. Can someone help me understand the difference between both approaches.

Approach 1:

```
class Student {
private _name: string;

constructor(name:string) {
    this._name=name;
}

getName = (): string => {
    return this._name;
}

setName = (name: string) => {
    this._name = name;
}
}
```

Approach 2:

```
class Student {
private _name: string;

constructor(name:string) {
    this._name=name;
}

public get name(): string {
    return this._name;
}


public set name(value: string) {
    this._name = value;
}
}
```

Have a look. In Approach 1 we write getter/setter as normal functions But in Approach 2 the keyword get/set is used. Can someone help me understand the difference between both approaches.

Comment: Have you tried using both? Didn't you notice any difference?

Comment: Yeah i tried using them both. And the difference i can see is .
In Approach 1: 
I can use for example :
myStudent.setName("ABCD");
console.log(mystudent.getName());     
       
But in  Approach 2 what i can do is
 myStudent.name="XYZ";
console.log(stu.name);

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The difference in the way you use them. In the first case you need to explictly call the `get/set` methdods. In the second you can use `name` like an actual field on the class and the runtime will call the `get/set` accessors automatically.

Consider the simple example of appending a character to the name:

Approach 1

```
let s = new Student();
s.setName(s.getName() + "A") // we need to explicitly call the get/ set methods
```

Approach 2

```
let s = new Student();
s.name += "A" // we can use += and the get/set accessors will get called for us
```

Behind the scene the `get/set` accessor approach (approach 2) will use [Object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)

Comment: Hi Titian Cernicova-Dragomir, Yeah i observed the same behavior. Any other major difference ?

Comment: Thanks for helping me out. I understood the difference. Also pointing out the use of Object.defineProperty helped.

Comment: @RajThakur That would be the main difference, I can't think of anything else taht would be important (except that approach 2 is not supported if you target es3 and might not work in very old browsers)