# Getter / Setter in Typescript without Class

Tags: javascript, typescript

Here is a sampling of SO questions for Typescript getters/setters: [from 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12827266/get-and-set-in-typescript), [Jan 2018](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37532530/typescript-getter-setter-convention), [Sept 2018](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51646513/getter-setter-in-typescript), among others.

That said, what is the recommended way for defining Typescript types for getters/setters in a vanilla JS object? That is, I would like a plain old javascript object without the `class` syntax, and to understand the best practices for typing. Here's the interface -

```
interface Store {
   activeEvent: Date
}
```

A few constraints for this object -

No `new` to instantiate

No duplicates - this doesn't work

```
const Store: Store = {
  activeEvent: new Date(),
  get activeEvent() {
    return this.activeEvent;
  },
}
```

No dangling underscores. Airbnb's eslint config is yelling at this -

```
const Store: Store = {
  _activeEvent: {},
  get activeEvent() {
    return this._activeEvent;
  },
```

Ideally I would like to have default values (that is, if I drop the key, the error goes away, but on first access `activeEvent` is undefined). I suppose I could init and return  `this.activeDate` if it is undefined, which works, but `get` is actually `get` & `set` in that scenario -

```
 get activeDate() {
    if(this.activeDate){ return this.activeDate }
    const date = new Date()
    this.activeDate = date;
    return date;
  },
```

I would rather not generate duplicate keys with getters and setters just to have getters and setters.

Interestingly enough, the fact that the getter/setter have the same key doesn't error out, it's just when they match the private-ish variable, which makes me think I am doing something wrong. I appreciate any insight.

[image: Error on getter setter]

Comment: `get activeEvent() {
    return this.activeEvent;
  },` <- this code is an infinite loop

Comment: "*No dangling underscores*" silly restriction, if you ask me. I'd personally just disable that rule. If you have `get activeEvent()` then you can't do `return activeEvent;` from inside it, since that would trigger the same getter. So you need the property and the getter named differently. Using an underscore is a well known convention for "private". You could just name it `this.xxxActiveEventxxx` or something - just append other stuff than an underscore, but it's silly. And if you name it as a *synonym* rather than the exact same thing, it's harder to maintain.

Comment: Why do you even want getters? Don't write them just to have getters. It's not the right way to have a default value. If you want a default value just add that default value instead of the getter

Comment: @zerkms heh, that is an infinite loop. I suppose the TS error is helpful.

Comment: @VLAZ, I agree the restriction lends itself to a maintenance problem.

Comment: @Lux, the example is obviously contrived. I am looking at some options for dynamically calculated properties, and would like a strongly-typed object with initial state living directly w/ the definition. I haven't used a getter/setter w/ typescript before, which led me here...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Wrap your object creation in a closure, and keep variables that aren't part of the interface outside the object:

```
function createStore() {
  let activeEvent = new Date();
  return {
    get activeEvent() {
      return activeEvent;
    },
  };
}
```

This avoids the name collision/infinite loop issue you're currently running into - the object you return has a `.activeEvent` getter, but the variable backing it lives outside the object, in the scope of the `createStore` function.

Comment: typo? `let activeDate` should be `let activeEvent`

Comment: From a data standpoint the closure is fine. I was hoping for some Typescript conventions, but you do answer the question as originally asked. Thanks for the note.

Comment: I don't think there are any special typescript conventions that will help here. If you want the data to be part of the object, I advise disabling the eslint rule as mentioned by other commenters.